# Angular SPA with Custom --base-href and Nginx Routing

Tags: angular, nginx

We have an angular SPA application that we need to change the base path from

[www.site.com](http://www.site.com)
to
[www.site.com/app](http://www.site.com/app)

We added `--base-href=/app` to our ng build command

```
RUN ng build --output-path=dist --base-href=/app/ --prod
```

We have this in our nginx configuration:

```
location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

We changed it to

```
location /app/ {
 root /usr/share/nginx/html/app;
 try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html;
}
```

and visiting the site `localhost/consumerhub` throws a 500 error. This is what I see in the logs:

```
2019/10/15 19:53:51 [error] 7#7: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/app/index.html", client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:9182"
172.17.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2019:19:53:51 +0000] "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1" 500 572 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

What should it be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the error, it seems that it's an internal redirect. And that's normal because your `try_files` statement says: try this, this, or `/app/index.html`, which starts a new location again. I'm not sure why you need the `root` inside your location. Can you try without that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng build --prod --base-href /app/ --deploy-url /app/` (change to your port number where the app runs(80))

```
  location /app/ {
      rewrite ^/app/(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass         http://localhost:80/app/;
      proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
```

Comment: this solution does not support routing. navigating to /app/page1 results in 404

Answer (score 1):

Solution without proxy_pass, just serving the compiled version:

```
location /app {
    alias /var/www/frontend;

    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
        expires -1;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|woff|otf|js|svg|css|txt|wav|mp3|aff|dic)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        expires 365d;
        access_log off;
    }

    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

location = / {
    return 301 /app;
}
```

- The important value is `=404`, otherwise the Angular subroutes get
  routed to some mysterios nginx spaces, instead to be returned to the
  Angular router.
- Make sure to have the base tag set in `angular.json` `"baseHref": "/app/",` in `architect.configurations.production`
- Also make sure to not set caching to json files if you use the
  Angular Service Worker, as it will fetch a json file that contains
  the build hashes to detect updates.

Comment: This does not work. All static content such as js and css files return 404 errors like `[error] 29#29: *2 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/css/main.bcf096cf.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Comment: @JeffreyTillwick I'm sorry, there was something missing. Please see my updated answer. It's running properly in production for a year now. But it seems your static file route is missing the base-href route. This is Angular issue, not by nginx

Comment: Complete solution, works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can add these parameters (--baseHref and --deployURL) in the angular.json configuration, for any environment or for all of them.